# How to set a current data in update() if the user is deleted in grails

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I have to set the current data in 'Date deletedDate' when the user is deleted. To do this I have to do it in Update() method: if deleted person, set deletedDate to current date.

I know that to set the current date I have to do:

deletedDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 30000))

But not sure how to do it inside of update or maybe is better create a service class to do is. If I have to create a new service, How can I know when the user is deleted?

Thanks in advanced

Domain:

```
class Person{
..
String nameID
Date deletedDate
}
```

Controller:

```
 def update(Long id, Long version) {
        def personInstance = Person.get(id)
        if (!personInstance) {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'person.label', default: 'Person'), id])
            redirect(action: "list")
            return
        }
        if (version != null) {
            if (personInstance.version > version) {
                personInstance.errors.rejectValue("version", "default.optimistic.locking.failure",
                          [message(code: 'person.label', default: 'Person')] as Object[],
                          "Another user has updated this Person while you were editing")
                render(view: "edit", model: [personInstance: personInstance])
                return
            }
        }
        personInstance.properties = params
        if (!personInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "edit", model: [personInstance: personInstance])
            return
        }
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'person.label', default: 'Person'), personInstance.id])
        redirect(action: "show", id: personInstance.id)
    }


    def delete(Long id) {
        def personInstance = Person.get(id)
        if (!personInstance) {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'person.label', default: 'Person'), id])
            redirect(action: "list")
            return
        }
        try {
            personInstance.delete(flush: true)
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'person.label', default: 'Person'), id])
            redirect(action: "list")
        }
        catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'person.label', default: 'Person'), id])
            redirect(action: "show", id: id)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (it worked for me in a similar case):

```
def delete(Long id) {
    def personInstance = Person.get(id)
    if (!personInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'person.label', default: 'Person'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }
    try {
        // deleteDate should be saved as well
        personInstance.deletedDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 30000))
        personInstance.delete(flush: true)
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'person.label', default: 'Person'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
    }
    catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'person.label', default: 'Person'), id])
        redirect(action: "show", id: id)
    }
}
```